# App sending spam messages to my contacts

Tags: sms, security, spam

My phone sent the following message to all of my contacts:

> Install this voice messenger just to talk http://mrv.withmechat.us/Cun

I know I didn't send this message and not to mention it sent it to all of my contacts at exactly 9:41AM. Is there a logger that can help me find what app or process sent that message?

Comment: Following the link leads to this app: [imo free video calls and chat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imo.android.imoim). You sure you didn't install this app? Otherwise, please refer to any questions related to [checking app permission](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44126/somethings-automatically-sending-stuff-from-my-phone/44131#44131).

Comment: You could find the default text messaging app in the settings

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem today. It was sent by the Imo app itself. Don't use or install this app!

I recommend leaving a bad review on the Play Store and reporting the app on the Play Store.

To find out which app sent the spam, you can use Android App Ops if it works on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest you go to settings -> Apps -> Click on the app -> Then uninstall. You could also just disable all permissions for the app if you wanted to keep it installed for some reason.